# OSX Xcode - program fails to load the library

Tags: macos, bundle, dyld

When I tried to run my program from the Terminal with `open dbhandler.app`, I am getting the following error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblibdbwindow.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/MacOS/dbhandler
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x10a633000 -        0x10a71cfff +abc.dbhandler (1.0 - 1) <0EED5BE6-858D-3F18-8B1D-B958B921C9F6> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/MacOS/dbhandler
       0x10a7b2000 -        0x10a86bfff +libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.dylib (0) <9ABAB987-AECF-3C7E-81D9-D20059AA7DE9> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.dylib
       0x10a978000 -        0x10aa1fff7 +libwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.2.dylib (0) <180E0A64-346F-3B51-B4E1-6E6F558B677F> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.2.dylib
       0x10ab17000 -        0x10ab39fff +libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.2.dylib (0) <0873DD66-C859-3CA8-BABB-11902927ED0D> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.2.dylib
       0x10ab75000 -        0x10ab79fff +libwx_osx_cocoau_adv-3.2.dylib (0) <E42305C2-8052-3475-969C-18A46AED5D79> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_osx_cocoau_adv-3.2.dylib
       0x10ab80000 -        0x10b25cff7 +libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.dylib (0) <58B0A14F-A6AB-33F0-A0B3-247E4452F59F> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.dylib
       0x10b9c4000 -        0x10b9d7ff7 +libwx_baseu_xml-3.2.dylib (0) <83568D4A-4344-33EF-8C91-C9D6E3268F09> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_baseu_xml-3.2.dylib
       0x10b9f3000 -        0x10ba40ff7 +libwx_baseu_net-3.2.dylib (0) <190BA3EF-89D4-3EFC-A385-C99C4770F78F> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_baseu_net-3.2.dylib
       0x10baad000 -        0x10bceeff7 +libwx_baseu-3.2.dylib (0) <F7F5E898-0082-34D8-A040-14C6F77D3EF2> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/libwx_baseu-3.2.dylib
       0x10bf07000 -        0x10bf81fff +liblibtabledataedit.dylib (0) <48F25B52-D3C6-3AF1-86A5-E1C22082ACEA> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibtabledataedit.dylib
       0x113d5f000 -        0x113da9acf  dyld (551.4) <8A72DE9C-A136-3506-AA02-4BA2B82DCAF3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff28983000 -     0x7fff28c11ff7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14) <E0B8B5D8-80A0-308B-ABD6-F8612102B5D8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff292e5000 -     0x7fff292e5fff  com.apple.Carbon (158 - 158) <F8B370D9-2103-3276-821D-ACC756167F86> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff297f7000 -     0x7fff297f7fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 22) <78E6C28E-4308-3D10-AD14-0CBCF6789B3F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff2c7e8000 -     0x7fff2c883fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1445.71.1) <2EA4F383-CAA9-3AF0-99C5-90C22ADAA6B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff34531000 -     0x7fff34540ff3  com.apple.opengl (16.7.4 - 16.7.4) <9BDE8FF9-5418-3C70-8D1C-09656884CE48> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff4fb8f000 -     0x7fff4fb90ffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1252.50.4) <CD555F3B-FDDB-35E5-A2FB-FBBF3D62031A> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM MBA71.0178.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000, Intel HD Graphics 6000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C3531324D3332443250462D3130
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C3531324D3332443250462D3130
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.31.1a9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

and this is an output on the Terminal:

```
Igors-MacBook-Air:Debug igorkorot$ open dbhandler.app/
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/dbhandler.app.
```

And this is the output of the Frameworks directory in the Bundle:

```
Igors-MacBook-Air:Debug igorkorot$ pwd
/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug
Igors-MacBook-Air:Debug igorkorot$ ls -la dbhandler.app/Contents/Frameworks/
total 189192
drwxr-xr-x  26 igorkorot  staff       832 Jan  1 21:17 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 igorkorot  staff       256 Jan  1 20:09 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   2415408 Jun  4  2018 libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    778384 Jun  4  2018 libclang_rt.ubsan_osx_dynamic.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    347052 Jan  1 21:17 liblibdbloader.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   6730348 Jan  1 21:17 liblibdbwindow.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   8906924 Jan  1 21:17 liblibdialogs.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    550680 Jan  1 21:17 liblibfieldswindow.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   3970352 Jan  1 21:17 liblibmysql.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   6383552 Jan  1 21:17 liblibodbc.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   4534984 Jan  1 21:17 liblibpostgres.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    466816 Jan  1 21:17 liblibpropertieshandlers.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   3015032 Jan  1 21:17 liblibpropertypages.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   5226584 Jan  1 21:17 liblibshapeframework.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff  15739876 Jan  1 21:17 liblibsqlite.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    896168 Jan  1 21:17 liblibtabledataedit.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   7340480 Jan  1 21:17 libmysqlclient.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   4524504 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_baseu-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    732432 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_baseu_net-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    163636 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_baseu_xml-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff     20944 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_osx_cocoau_adv-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff  14883612 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   1686416 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff    356864 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   4408276 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_osx_cocoau_stc-3.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 igorkorot  staff   1821868 Jan  1 21:17 libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.dylib
Igors-MacBook-Air:Debug igorkorot$
```

What is the best way to find out what library is at fault?

Answer (score 0):

You have `liblibdbwindow.dylib` in your app's Contents/Frameworks folder, but the error message says that it is expected to be in /usr/local/lib.  If you issue the terminal command

```
otool -L /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/dbhandler.app/Contents/MacOS/dbhandler
```

then I expect that to show that your app binary is looking for the dylib in /usr/local/lib.  And if you do `otool -L` on `liblibdbwindow.dylib`, the first line of output (the "shared library ID") will presumably also be `/usr/local/lib/liblibdbwindow.dylib`.  To fix this, you'll need to make changes in both the dylib and the app executable.

Assuming that `liblibdbwindow.dylib` is something you are building yourself, set the build setting `INSTALL_PATH` in the dylib target to `@rpath`.  (If it's not your code, you'll need to use `install_name_tool` to fix it.)

In the target for the app, the build setting `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` should include something like `@loader_path/../Frameworks`.